# C Initialize Character Array from Character Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, initialization

My question should be rather simple.

I need to give a function a char array of a pre-defined length, but I have a character pointer with variable length, but not longer than the length of my array.

Here the code:

```
#define SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME 50
char person[SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME];
char* currentPerson = "John";
```

now how would I get John into the person array but also setting the rest of the array to 0 (/NUL) ?

so that I would have

```
BINARY DATA: "John/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL/NUL....."
```

in my memory?

sorry if this is overly stupid, but I can't seem to find a solution right now.

Comment: why don't you use `std::string`.

Comment: using old C libraries

Comment: Duplicate? use strcpy http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: are you having a `NULL`-terminated `char*`? If yes, then, as @CasperVonB just mentioned, use `strcpy`. Otherwise you need to know the length and use a `memcpy`

Comment: A lot of effort has been spend by C++/STL implementers to materialize `std::string` in order for application programmers to avoid all the shortcomings of playing with old C char buffers.

Comment: I agree with all of you guys. I still can't help the fact, working on a project from 2004 which would take me years to upgrade to higher standarts. I just need to pass a character array, as described above, to that old library. If someone has an idea how to do this via memset or smth else, please share it with me.

Comment: @user2334932 Who told you, that you can't use `std::string` to pass a `const char*` parameter elsewhere? Ever heard of [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)?

Comment: Title says C, poster says C and the code looks like C what gives with the C++ answers? ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No one :P but I don't need a char*. I need a char[]

Comment: @CasperVonB: original tagging was C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, zero-initialize the fixed-size array :

```
// Using memset here because I don't know if the whole copy operation can or will be used
// multiple times. We want to be sure that the array is properly zero-initialized if the next
// string to copy is shorter than the previous.
memset(person, '\0', SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME);
```

Then, copy the variable-size string into it :

```
strcpy(person, currentPerson);
```

If you are not certain that `currentPerson` will fit into `person` :

```
strncpy(person, currentPerson, SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME - 1);
```

---

Note that `strncpy` also zero-initialize the remaining bytes of the array if

```
strlen(currentPerson) < SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME - 1
```

So you basically have these two options :

```
memset(person, '\0', SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME);
strcpy(person, currentPerson);
```

Or :

```
strncpy(person, currentPerson, SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME - 1);
person[SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Why `memset` and not just `char person[SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME] = {'\0'};`

Comment: @40two That works too but only at initialization time, with memset (or even bzero), there is no such restriction.

Comment: the `memset` (instead of shorter, simpler and safer C++ curly braces initialization) jars with the use of `strncopy` as a "Safer version.". extreme disharmony here. my ears!

Comment: Thank you a lot Chnossos. I know that the standarts of C++ improved. You still sometimes got to deal with old libraries and go back to old standarts. This seems to be the best way to do this. Question Answered

Comment: Never use `strncpy` as a **safer** `strcpy`: ***It is not!*** Also, `sizeof(char)` reads "I don't know any C..."

Comment: @Deduplicator It is safer if you use it correctly since it requires you to pick a correct third argument. Or I am wrong ? Also, I usually never use `sizeof(char)` but I've been told that it doesn't equal 1 everywhere so I thought it'd be better. Or do you mean I should have written `sizeof(*person)` ?

Comment: @Chnossos: [The semantics of `strncpy` mean that the added third argument does not make it any safer to use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25110646). And `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, and by definition `sizeof` gives the length in bytes aka `char`. How many bytes is one byte long? Not one?

Comment: In my answer, I didn't mean that `strncpy` was safer in itself, this specific use was safer only if called **after** memset since we were now sure that the buffer was zero-initialized. But I see where you come from, and thanks to you I know more about sizeof. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>After this answer was posted the question was retagged from C++ to C.</sup>

Use a `std::string`, like this:

```
// "using namespace std;" or "using std::string;", then:

string const person = currentPerson;
old_c_function( person.c_str() );
```

---

To do things at the C level, which I recommend that you don't, first replace the unnecessary `#define` with a typed constant:

```
int const max_person_name_size = 50;
```

Then zero-initialize your array:

```
char person[max_person_name_size] = {};
```

(Note: no silly `memset` here.)
(Also note: this zeroing is only a preventive measure. You wanted it. But it's not really necessary since `strcpy` will ensure a trailing zero-byte.)

Then just copy in the string:

```
assert( strlen( current_person ) < max_person_name_size );
strcpy( person, current_person );
```

But don't do this. Use `std::string` instead.

---

**Update**: doing other things for some minutes made me realize that this answer, as all the others so far, is completely **off the mark**. The OP states in [a comment elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110302/c-initialize-character-array-from-character-pointer/25110371#comment39077737_25110321) that

> **”**  I've got a function in the library which only takes a character array. Not a character pointer.

Thus, apparently it's all about a misconception.

The only way this can make sense is if the array is modified by the function, and then `std::string::c_str()` is not a solution. But a `std::string` can still be used, if its length is set to something sufficient for the C function. Can go like this:

```
person.resize( max_person_name_size );
foo( &person[0] );                // Assuming foo modifies the array.
person.resize( strlen( person.c_str() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

With literal, you may do:

```
char person[SIZE_MAX_PERSON_NAME] = "John";
```

if c-string is not a literal, you have to do the copy with `strcpy`

```
strcpy(person, currentPerson);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one and only reason for the existence of `strncpy`:

Putting a string (up to the 0-terminator or buffer end) into a fixed-length array and zeroing out the rest.
*This does not ensure 0-termination,* thus **avoid it for anything else.**

> ### 7.24.2.4 The `strncpy` function
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strncpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> 2 The `strncpy` function copies not more than `n` characters (characters that follow a null
>   character are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the array pointed to by `s1`.<sub>308)</sub> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   3 If the array pointed to by `s2` is a string that is shorter than `n` characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by `s1`, until `n` characters in all have been written.
>   4 The `strncpy` function returns the value of `s1`.